# Condition check for multiple Async functions

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 with Angular.

I have multiple asyn functions:

```
async buildNewsItemsViaHttp(){
  let result = await this.http.get()....
}

async buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON(){
   return await this.http.get()....
}

async getNewsItems(){
   return await this.storage.get()...
}
```

I would like to run the async functions conditionally based on if they return a value or not. This means:

- if getNewsItems() would return data, return it
- if not, run buildNewsItemsViaHttp and see if it returns data
- if not, run buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON

Suggestion:

```
async getItems(){
    let result = await.this.getNewsItems();
    if (result) {
        return result;
    } else {
        result = await.this.buildNewsItemsViaHttp();
        if (result) {
            return result;
        } else {            
            result = await.this.buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this solution correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks fine, but you don't need to use an `else` when the if branch returns. So you could simplify a little bit by removing those.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sort of chaining to achieve what you want, this below is a bit naive but should work:

```
getNewsItems().then((result)=>{
    if (result === "what you need") {
        // do here what you want with the result data
    } else {
         buildNewsItemsViaHttp().then((result)=>{
             if (result === "what you need") {
                  // do here what you want with the result data
             } else {
                 buildNewsItemsViaLocalJSON.then((result)=>{
                 // do here what you need with result
             })
         }
    })
}})
```

And of course you should also have logic to catch errors (.catch(err)=>{})